Upgrade version 5.3.3 to version 5.19.4
When I want to upgrade version 5.3.3 to version 5.19.4 I get an error like the following.
What are the minimum system requirements?

Typescript => 6.14.5
Nodejs => 12.18.2


FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

I was expecting to upgrade to 5.19.4 but I can't upgrade
